# Changing the gradient of a line by degrees

Tags: analytic-geometry

I know that to find the perpendicular of a linear line of form $y = m x + c$, you create a new equation with a gradient of the negative reciprocal $-1/m$. This is how you change it by 90 degrees. Is there a way of doing this by 30 degrees say? Is there a formula for rotating lines?

Comment: Do you know how to [rotate coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)#Two_dimensions)?

Comment: One way is to use the formula for the tangent of the sum of two angles.

Comment: The angle is given by $\arctan(m)$.